# How do I execute/bundle JS with Webpack from another task runner?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I've been using `webpack` for my latest projects, but I have legacy projects using `grunt` or `gulp` or other.

In those cases, I'd still love a bundler like `webpack` with ultra minimal configs to use ES6 imports and such.

How do I execute a single `webpack` bundle command from within say `gulp` or longrunning node script?

I can spawn a subprocess and call `webpack` but I'm curious how I'd use it in legacy toolchains via JS.

```
webpack({...}) // does nothing
```

I found the use of `webpack().apply()` on some other stack overflow post  and `webpack` *does* compile once, but not a second time when called within a `gulp` task.

```
(function exampleCreateBundle() => {
    const compiler = webpack({
      entry: './_js/index.js',
      output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'js')
      }
    });
    compiler.apply(new ProgressPlugin(function(percentage, msg) {
       console.log((percentage * 100) + '%', msg);
    }));

    // works once
})();
```

Thanks for any help!

Update:

Honestly, I'm just spawning a child process and running `npx webpack`.

At this point the question is academic.